# How can I update multiple columns in R using loop?

Tags: r, loops

In R, I wanted to update columns named GW_gen$q1, GW_gen$q2,... with values multiplied by -1. 
I found that I can make new variables named temp1, temp2,.. with below code.

```
for (i in 1:81) {
  assign(paste0("temp", i), -1*eval(parse(text=paste0("GW_gen$q", i))));
}
```

However, I could not update values in original columns.

```
for (i in 1:81) {
  assign(paste0("GW_gen$q", i), -1*eval(parse(text=paste0("GW_gen$q", i))));
}
```

Comment: Just try `GW_gen[,c("q1","q2")]<- -GW_gen[,c("q1","q2")]`.

Comment: Great. Just so simple!